# File/folder permissions for remote users in Windows Server 2012

Tags: tomcat, permissions, windows-server-2012

I have a problem with setting up permissions on Windows server 2012.

Here is the setup and how it should work:

- Java application is run on Tomcat 7.5 on Windows server 2012
- Java application should be able to create Word document based on Word template
- user connects remotely through his web browser onto application to use it, creates .doc document based on the .dot template.  After that the user should be able to open created Word document

The problem is this:
-the remote user can do everything in application but it can't generate word file if one of the admin users is not logged onto server in the same time as user tries to generate a file

Also, if the file is already generated, remotely connected user can open it without a problem if admin is not logged on.

I think this is definitely problem with permissions but I don't know which ones. I've tried to put permissions for all users ('Everyone','Users','REMOTE LOGO USER', 'NETWORK SERVICE') on folder that holds generated files, but no such luck.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This sounds more suitable for [su]

Answer (score 0):

Somebody might find it helpful once.....It wasn't about directory permissions in the end. I've had to change Identity from Interactive user to This User (admin user) in Computed Services for Microsoft Word Document